# How to handle button click inside recycler view item in Xamarin Android?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

[image]

here is the item inside recycler view,so I want to increase and decrease the quantity by clicking plus and minus button.How to do this in xamarin android?

here is my adapter

```
public class OrderDetailsItemAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter
    {
        List<OrderItem> orderItemList = new List<OrderItem>();
        RecyclerView orderItemsRecyclerView;
        private object orderListitems;
        private RecyclerView recyclerview;
        Context _context;

        public OrderDetailsItemAdapter(List<OrderItem> orderItemList, RecyclerView recyclerview,Context context)
        {
            this.orderItemList = orderItemList;
            this.recyclerview = recyclerview;
            _context = context;
        }

        public override int ItemCount
        {
            get
            {
                return orderItemList.Count;
            }
        }

        public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
        {
            OrderDetailsItemViewHolder viewHolder = holder as OrderDetailsItemViewHolder;

            viewHolder.OrderItemCheckBox.Checked = orderItemList[position].IsChecked;
            viewHolder.OrderItemSKU.Text = $"SKU: {orderItemList[position].SKU}";
            viewHolder.KitIcon.Visibility = orderItemList[position].IsKit ? ViewStates.Visible : ViewStates.Invisible;
            viewHolder.OrderItemKitSKU.Text = $"KIT SKU: {orderItemList[position].KitSKU}";
            viewHolder.OrderItemQty.Text = $"REQ QTY: {orderItemList[position].OrderQuantity.ToString()}";

            viewHolder.OrderItemShipQty.Text = orderItemList[position].ShipQuantity.ToString();
        }


        public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context);
            View itemView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.order_details_layout_view, parent, false);
            return new OrderDetailsItemViewHolder(itemView);
        }
    }
```

so how to get the position of the item on button click?

Comment: Did you want to pass the position to the activity and handle the logic?

Comment: Actually I want to update quantity the EditText on Plus/Minus button click.How to do this?how to notify this?

Comment: Added an answer below take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle the logic in method **OnBindViewHolder**

```
public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
{
    RecyclerViewHolder myHolder = holder as RecyclerViewHolder;
    myHolder.Add_Button.Click +=(o,e)=> {
        mEmails[position].MyCount = mEmails[position].MyCount + 1;
        myHolder.editText1.Text = mEmails[position].MyCount.ToString();

    };
    myHolder.reduce_Button.Click += (o, e) =>
    {
        mEmails[position].MyCount = mEmails[position].MyCount - 1;
        myHolder.editText1.Text = mEmails[position].MyCount.ToString();
    };

    myHolder.mName.Text = mEmails[position].Name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use the ElegantButton control which is a custom control for this exact purpose

```
  public class ElegantNumberButton : RelativeLayout
{
    private Context context;
    private IAttributeSet attrs;
    private int styleAttr;
    private IOnClickListener mListener;
    private int initialNumber;
    private int lastNumber;
    private int currentNumber;
    private int finalNumber;
    private TextView textView;
    private Button addBtn, subtractBtn;
    private View view;
    private IOnValueChangeListener mOnValueChangeListener;

    public ElegantNumberButton(Context context) : base(context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        InitView();
    }

    public ElegantNumberButton(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.attrs = attrs;
        InitView();
    }

    public ElegantNumberButton(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) : base(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.attrs = attrs;
        this.styleAttr = defStyleAttr;
        InitView();
    }

    private void InitView()
    {
        this.view = this;
        Inflate(context, Resource.Layout.layout, this);
        Resources res = this.Resources;
        int defaultColor = ResourcesCompat.GetColor(res, Resource.Color.colorPrimary, null);
        int defaultTextColor = ResourcesCompat.GetColor(res, Resource.Color.colorPrimary, null);
        Drawable defaultDrawable = res.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.background);

        TypedArray a = context.ObtainStyledAttributes(attrs, Resource.Styleable.ElegantNumberButton, styleAttr, 0);

        initialNumber = a.GetInt(Resource.Styleable.ElegantNumberButton_initialNumber, 0);
        finalNumber = a.GetInt(Resource.Styleable.ElegantNumberButton_finalNumber, int.MaxValue);
        float textSize = a.GetDimension(Resource.Styleable.ElegantNumberButton_textSize, 13);
        var color = a.GetColor(Resource.Styleable.ElegantNumberButton_backGroundColor, defaultColor);
        var textColor = a.GetColor(Resource.Styleable.ElegantNumberButton_textColor, defaultTextColor);
        Drawable drawable = a.GetDrawable(Resource.Styleable.ElegantNumberButton_backgroundDrawable);

        subtractBtn = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.subtract_btn);
        addBtn = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.add_btn);
        textView = (TextView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.number_counter);
        LinearLayout mLayout = (LinearLayout)FindViewById(Resource.Id.layout);

        subtractBtn.SetTextColor(textColor);
        addBtn.SetTextColor(textColor);
        textView.SetTextColor(textColor);
        subtractBtn.SetTextSize(ComplexUnitType.Sp, textSize);
        addBtn.SetTextSize(ComplexUnitType.Sp, textSize);
        textView.SetTextSize(ComplexUnitType.Sp, textSize);

        if (drawable == null)
        {
            drawable = defaultDrawable;
        }

        drawable.SetColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.Src));
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt > BuildVersionCodes.JellyBean)
            mLayout.Background = (drawable);
        else

            mLayout.SetBackgroundDrawable(drawable);


        textView.SetText(initialNumber);

        currentNumber = initialNumber;
        lastNumber = initialNumber;
        subtractBtn.Click += SubtractBtn_Click;
        addBtn.Click += AddBtn_Click;
        a.Recycle();
    }
    private void SubtractBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int num = int.Parse(textView.Text);
        SetNumber((num - 1).ToString(), true);
    }

    private void AddBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int num = int.Parse(textView.Text.ToString());
        SetNumber((num + 1).ToString(), true);
    }


    private void CallListener(View view)
    {
        if (mListener != null)
        {
            mListener.OnClick(view);
        }

        if (mOnValueChangeListener != null)
        {
            if (lastNumber != currentNumber)
            {
                mOnValueChangeListener.OnValueChange(this, lastNumber, currentNumber);
            }
        }
    }

    public string GetNumber()
    {
        return (currentNumber).ToString();
    }

    public void SetNumber(string number)
    {
        lastNumber = currentNumber;
        this.currentNumber = int.Parse(number);
        if (this.currentNumber > finalNumber)
        {
            this.currentNumber = finalNumber;
        }
        if (this.currentNumber < initialNumber)
        {
            this.currentNumber = initialNumber;
        }
        textView.Text = currentNumber.ToString();
    }

    public void SetNumber(string number, bool notifyListener)
    {
        SetNumber(number);
        if (notifyListener)
        {
            CallListener(this);
        }
    }

    public void SetOnClickListener(IOnClickListener onClickListener)
    {
        this.mListener = onClickListener;
    }

    public void SetOnValueChangeListener(IOnValueChangeListener onValueChangeListener)
    {
        mOnValueChangeListener = onValueChangeListener;
    }

    public interface IOnClickListener
    {
        void OnClick(View view);
    }

    public interface IOnValueChangeListener
    {
        void OnValueChange(ElegantNumberButton view, int oldValue, int newValue);
    }

    public void SetRange(int startingNumber, int endingNumber)
    {
        this.initialNumber = startingNumber;
        this.finalNumber = endingNumber;
    }

    public void UpdateColors(Android.Graphics.Color backgroundColor, Android.Graphics.Color textColor)
    {
        this.textView.SetBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
        this.addBtn.SetBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
        this.subtractBtn.SetBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);

        this.textView.SetTextColor(textColor);
        this.addBtn.SetTextColor(textColor);
        this.subtractBtn.SetTextColor(textColor);
    }

    public void UpdateTextSize(float newSize)
    {
        this.textView.SetTextSize(ComplexUnitType.Sp, newSize);
        this.addBtn.SetTextSize(ComplexUnitType.Sp, newSize);
        this.subtractBtn.SetTextSize(ComplexUnitType.Sp, newSize);
    }
}
```

All the resources that you need here will be available in the following git:

https://github.com/ashik94vc/ElegantNumberButton/tree/master/lib/src/main

Once you use this in your xml you can get the data from the object using the `GetNumber` method.

Comment: unable to understand properly.Can you see my code any suggest the changes,and how to implement notify property?

Comment: This is `Xamarin.Android`, not `Xamarin.Forms` you cannot do that here you will have to manually do that!

Comment: do you have any easy sample for this?so that I can understand

Comment: When you say example what exactly do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old post, but in any case, I like to help
You manage the Click event on your Binding function on the adapter, but to prevent many times to call the event I suggest to use a property from the button that tells you if it has or not a ClickEvent registered previously:

```
public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        OrderDetailsItemViewHolder viewHolder = holder as OrderDetailsItemViewHolder;

        viewHolder.OrderItemCheckBox.Checked = orderItemList[position].IsChecked;
        viewHolder.OrderItemSKU.Text = $"SKU: {orderItemList[position].SKU}";
        viewHolder.KitIcon.Visibility = orderItemList[position].IsKit ? ViewStates.Visible : ViewStates.Invisible;
        viewHolder.OrderItemKitSKU.Text = $"KIT SKU: {orderItemList[position].KitSKU}";
        viewHolder.OrderItemQty.Text = $"REQ QTY: {orderItemList[position].OrderQuantity.ToString()}";

        viewHolder.OrderItemShipQty.Text = orderItemList[position].ShipQuantity.ToString();

      if(!viewHolder.MyButton.HasOnClickListener){
          viewHolder.MyButton.Click += (s, e) =>{
            //TO DO
            }
        }
    }
```